# How I can get address of dlopen()/dlsym() provided by the OS

Tags: c, linux, hook, libc

I need to implement hooks for dlsym() and dlopen() syscalls. In order to call the original dlsym() from the hook, I need to get the address of this syscall. I try to get address in the so-library-constructor-function. But I am getting only the address of the hook function. I tried to specify as a handler as RTLD_DEFAULT, well as RTLD_NEXT. When using RTLD_DEFAULT, I get NULL. When using RTLD_NEXT, I get the address of the hook function.
dlopen() I can`t be used for the same reason, because I have the hook on dlopen().

Tell me, please, how can I get the address of the original dlopen() and dlsym() functions?

Thanks.

Comment: `RTLD_NEXT` is designed for exactly this purpose: to get the original binding of the symbol. If you call it from the hook library, you shouldn't be getting the hook function, you should be getting the function from the C library. A short compilable example that demonstrates the problem would help.

Comment: example code here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/955dd416ce716b8a5682d121fe399490

Comment: you could use `dladdr(3)` on Gnu/Linux.

Comment: There is good information about this topic in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825060/737427

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`__libc_dlsym()`](http://50hz.ws/docs/dlsymwrap.html) is the `dlsym()` as provided by the libc. `dlopen()` has its own counterpart as `__libc_dlopen()`.

Comment: This info may be outdated.  It seems to segfault now.  There is updated information available here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18825060/737427