# How can I intercept dlsym calls using LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: c++, c, intercept, ld-preload, dlsym

I want to intercept application's calls to dlsym. I have tried declaring inside the .so that I am preloading dlsym , and using dlsym itself to get it's real address, but that for quite obvious reasons didn't work.

Is there a way easier than taking process' memory maps, and using libelf to find the real location of dlsym inside loaded libdl.so?

Comment: Is is code part of the question or an answer? Can you either edit into your question or post it as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

**WARNING**:

I have to explicitely warn everyone who tries to do this. The general premise of having a shared library hooking `dlsym` has several significant drawbacks. The biggest issue issue is that the original `dlsym` implementation if glibc will internally use stack unwinding techniques to find out from which loaded module the function was called. If the intercepting shared library then calls the original `dlsym` on behalf of the original application, this will **break** lookups using  stuff like `RTLD_NEXT`, as now the current module isn't the originally calling one, but your hook library.

It might be possible to implement this the correct way, but it requires a lot more work. Without having tried it, I think that using `dlinfo` to get to the chained list of linket maps, you could individually walk through all modules, and do a separate `dlsym` for each one, to get the `RTLD_NEXT` behavior right. You still need to get the address of your caller for that, which you might get via the old `backtrace(3)` family of functions.

**MY OLD ANSWER FROM 2013**

I stumbled across the same problem with hdante's answer as the commenter: calling `__libc_dlsym()` directly crashes with a segfault. After reading some glibc sources, I came up with the following hack as a workaround:

```
extern void *_dl_sym(void *, const char *, void *);
extern void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *name)
{
    /* my target binary is even asking for dlsym() via dlsym()... */
    if (!strcmp(name,"dlsym")) 
        return (void*)dlsym;
    return _dl_sym(handle, name, dlsym);
}
```

NOTE two things with this "solution":

1. This code bypasses the locking which is done internally by `(__libc_)dlsym()`, so to make this threadsafe, you should add some locking.
2. The thrid argument of `_dl_sym()` is the address of the caller, glibc seems to reconstruct this value by stack unwinding, but I just use the address of the function itself. The caller address is used internally to find the link map the caller is in to get things like `RTLD_NEXT` right (and, using NULL as thrid argument will make the call fail with an error when using `RTLD_NEXT`). However, I have not looked at glibc's unwindind functionality, so I'm not 100% sure that the above code will do the right thing, and it may happen to work just by chance alone...

The solution presented so far has some significant drawbacks: `_dl_sym()` acts quite differently than the intended `dlsym()` in some situations. For example, trying to resolve a symbol which does not exist does exit the program instead of just returning NULL. To work around that, one can use `_dl_sym()` to just get the pointer to the original `dlsym()` and use that for everything else (like in the "standard" `LD_PRELOAD` hook approch without hooking `dlsym` at all):

```
extern void *_dl_sym(void *, const char *, void *);
extern void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *name)
{
    static void * (*real_dlsym)(void *, const char *)=NULL;
    if (real_dlsym == NULL)
        real_dlsym=_dl_sym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlsym", dlsym);
    /* my target binary is even asking for dlsym() via dlsym()... */
    if (!strcmp(name,"dlsym")) 
        return (void*)dlsym;
    return real_dlsym(handle,name);
}
```

**UPDATE FOR 2021 / glibc-2.34**

Beginning with glibc 2.34, the function `_dl_sym()` is no longer publicly exported. Another approach I can suggest is to use `dlvsym()` instead, which is offically part of the glibc API and ABI. The only downside is that you now need the exact version to ask for the `dlsym` symbol. Fortunately, that is also part of the glibc ABI, unfortunately, it varies per architecture. However, a `grep 'GLIBC_.*\bdlsym\b' -r sysdeps` in the root folder of the glibc sources will tell you what you need:

```
[...]
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/libc.abilist:GLIBC_2.0 dlsym F
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/libc.abilist:GLIBC_2.34 dlsym F
[...]
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/libc.abilist:GLIBC_2.2.5 dlsym F
sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/64/libc.abilist:GLIBC_2.34 dlsym F
```

Glibc-2.34 actually introduced new versions of this function, but the old versions are still be kept around for backwards compatibilty.

For x86_64, you could use:

```
real_dlsym=dlvsym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlsym", "GLIBC_2.2.5");
```

And, if you both like to get the newest version, as well as a potentially one of *another* interceptor in the same process, you can use that version to do an unversioned query again:

```
real_dlsym=real_dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlsym");
```

If you actually need to hook both `dlsym` and `dlvsym` in your shared object, this approach of course won't work either.

**UPDATE: hooking both `dlsym()` and `dlvsym()` at the same time**

Out of curiosity, I thought about some approach to hook both of the glibc symbol query methods, and I came up with a solution using an additional wrapper library which links to `libdl`. The idea is that the interceptor library can dynamically load this library at runtime using `dlopen()` with the `RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND` flags, which will create a separate linker scope for this object, also containing the `libdl`, so that the `dlsym` and `dlvsym` will be resolved to the original methods, and not the one in the interceptor library. The problem now is that our interceptor library can not directly call any function inside the wrapper library, because we can not use `dlsym`, which is our original problem.

However, the shared library can have an initialization function, which the linker will call before the `dlopen()` returns. We just need to pass some information from the initialization function of the wrapper library to the interceptor library. Since both are in the same process, we can use the environment block for that.

This is the code I came up with:

`dlsym_wrapper.h`:

```
#ifndef DLSYM_WRAPPER_H
#define DLSYM_WRAPPER_H

#define DLSYM_WRAPPER_ENVNAME "DLSYM_WRAPPER_ORIG_FPTR"
#define DLSYM_WRAPPER_NAME "dlsym_wrapper.so"
typedef void* (*DLSYM_PROC_T)(void*, const char*);

#endif
```

`dlsym_wrapper.c`, compiled to `dlsym_wrapper.so`:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "dlsym_wrapper.h"

__attribute__((constructor))
static void dlsym_wrapper_init()
{
    if (getenv(DLSYM_WRAPPER_ENVNAME) == NULL) {
        /* big enough to hold our pointer as hex string, plus a NUL-terminator */
        char buf[sizeof(DLSYM_PROC_T)*2 + 3];
        DLSYM_PROC_T dlsym_ptr=dlsym;
        if (snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%p", dlsym_ptr) < (int)sizeof(buf)) {
            buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = 0;
            if (setenv(DLSYM_WRAPPER_ENVNAME, buf, 1)) {
                // error, setenv failed ...
            }
        } else {
            // error, writing pointer hex string failed ...
        }
    } else {
        // error: environment variable already set ...
    }
}
```

And one function in the interceptor library to get the pointer to the
original `dlsym()` (should be called only once, guared by a mutex):

```
static void *dlsym_wrapper_get_dlsym
{
    char dlsym_wrapper_name = DLSYM_WRAPPER_NAME;
    void *wrapper;
    const char * ptr_str;
    void *res = NULL;
    void *ptr = NULL;

    if (getenv(DLSYM_WRAPPER_ENVNAME)) {
        // error: already defined, shoudn't be...
    }
    wrapper = dlopen(dlsym_wrapper_name, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND | RTLD_NOLOAD);
    if (wrapper) {
        // error: dlsym_wrapper.so already loaded ...
        // it is important that we load it by ourselves to a sepearte linker scope
    }
    wrapper = dlopen(dlsym_wrapper_name, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND);
    if (!wrapper) {
        // error: dlsym_wrapper.so can't be loaded
    }

    ptr_str = getenv(DLSYM_WRAPPER_ENVNAME);
    if (!ptr_str) {
        // error: dlsym_wrapper.so failed...
    }
    if (sscanf(ptr_str, "%p", &ptr) == 1) {
        if (ptr) {
            // success!
            res = ptr;
        } else {
            // error: got invalid pointer ...
        }
    } else {
        // error: failed to parse pointer...
    }

    // this is a bit evil: close the wrapper. we can be sure
    // that libdl still is used, as this mosule uses it (dlopen)
    dlclose(wrapper);

    return res;
}
```

This of course assumes that `dlsym_wrapper.so` is in the library search path. However, you may prefer to just inject the interceptor library via `LD_PRELOAD` using a full path, and not modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all. To do so, you can add `dladdr(dlsym_wrapper_get_dlsym,...)` to find the path of the injector library itself, and use that for searching the wrapper library, too.

Comment: Your `real_dlsym` takes 3 arguments, but you just call it with `real_dlsym(handle,ptr)`, where `ptr` is not even a variable.

Comment: @lama12345: You are correct. I updated my answer to fix those copy&paste errors.

Comment: Two pieces of bad news for you: 1. You were right about your code not always doing the right thing with regard to `RTLD_NEXT`. 2. Citrix adds a library to `/etc/ld.so.preload` that apparently copied and pasted the code from your answer without heeding your warning, which is breaking things for people ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68128568/7509065), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337541/7509065)).

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the heads-up. There is not much I can do about this, unfortunately. As I wrote in the answer long time ago, one only should use this hack to only ever get a pointer to `dlsym` itself, and let _that_ do the handlig of every other lookup (which will also get the flags like `RTLD_NEXT` right...)

Comment: Alternative way to get the version string without using the glibc source code:
readelf -a -W /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so | grep "dlsym"

Answer (score -1):

http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/08/lets-hook-a-library-function/

From the text:

> Do beware of functions that themselves call dlsym(), when you need to call __libc_dlsym (handle, symbol) in the hook.

```
extern void *__libc_dlsym (void *, const char *);
void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol)
{
    printf("Ha Ha...dlsym() Hooked\n");
    void* result = __libc_dlsym(handle, symbol); /* now, this will call dlsym() library function */
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This seems to segfault, i've even tried to compile just that code alone , same result

Comment: same @user1588911