# Hooking framework (Detours-like)

Tags: c, linux, hook, hotpatching

I am looking for a C library/framework that allows me to replace functions in memory and redirect them to my own implementations, while still allowing my implementation to call the original implementation.

This seems to be a rather rare need on Linux-y systems, presumably because LD_PRELOAD covers most aspects of runtime-function-replacing-thingies.

Comment: Why isn't LD_PRELOAD enough? Or just patching the source itself?

Comment: LD_PRELOAD -> does not cover cases where the target application loads the to-be-patched library directly via manual calls to dlopen/dlsym etc. Patching the source -> not an option, target applications tend to be large and/or closed source. The next option would be ofc. to generate a library wrapping the entire to-be-patched library, but I'd *really* like to avoid that. FYI it's about overriding glXSwapBuffers/eglSwapBuffers to inject post-processing effects (SMAA mainly).

Comment: @dom0: You could interpose `dlsym()` itself (although there are a couple of [pitfalls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15599026/how-can-i-intercept-dlsym-calls-using-ld-preload)), as long as the target application is dynamically linked and uses libdl.

Comment: I tried that, but there seem to be quite some interesting issues with it (I might create another question for it). E.g. without a mutex around any call to __libc_dlsym it *will* crash, sometimes even in single-threaded programs. Also, some applications (e.g. Steam) are highly allergic to someone overriding dlsym, even when minding all the tips and hints you find on the net. For example, with Steam, some background processes keep crashing in unrelated locations. Probably caused by very slight and minor behaviour (runtime?) changes. (Even when ret 0 if dlsym ret'ed 0 to be safe it does so).

Comment: So I personally feel like it is *less of an hack* to wait until the application started up, inject a .so of our own and detour glXSwapBuffers, instead of interposing intricate details of the dynamic linker. (E.g. derhass's answer you linked did not work for me at all ; all calls to _dl_sym crash, while __libc_dlsym is fine - see above - under certain cicrumstances).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach seems to work on applications I have. I don't like proprietary blobs on my machines, so I don't know if it works with e.g. Steam. I'd be very interested to know, though; I don't see any reason why it shouldn't.

The following approach uses `_dl_vsym()` to look up correctly versioned `dlsym()` and `dlvsym()` from `libdl.so` prior to `main()` being executed. During application execution, the interposed `dlsym()` and `dlvsym()` call their original versions (*not* `_dl_vsym()`); I believe that should avoid any application-specific woes.

In case other dynamic libraries get initialized before this one, very careful initial versions of those functions are used. They use `_dl_vsym()` to obtain the references to the libdl `dlsym()` or `dlvsym()` function; any subsequent call will use the libdl `dlsym()` or `dlvsym()`. This limits the fragile time to the first call during library initialization -- but the priority 101 hopefully gets this library initialized first.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <EGL/egl.h>

#define UNUSED __attribute__((unused))

#define LIBDL_VERSION "GLIBC_2.2.5"
#define LIBDL_PATH    "libdl.so"

extern void *_dl_vsym(void *, const char *, const char *, void *);

static const struct {
    const char *const symbol;
    const char *const version;
    void *const       function;
} interposed[] = {
    { "dlsym",          LIBDL_VERSION,   dlsym  },
    { "dlvsym",         LIBDL_VERSION,   dlvsym },
    { "glXSwapBuffers", (const char *)0, glXSwapBuffers },
    { "eglSwapBuffers", (const char *)0, eglSwapBuffers },
    { (const char *)0,  (const char *)0, (void *)0 }
};

static void *       initial_dlsym(void *, const char *);
static void *       initial_dlvsym(void *, const char *, const char *);
static void         initial_glXSwapBuffers(Display *, GLXDrawable);
static EGLBoolean   initial_eglSwapBuffers(EGLDisplay, EGLSurface);

static void *     (*actual_dlsym)(void *, const char *)                = initial_dlsym;
static void *     (*actual_dlvsym)(void *, const char *, const char *) = initial_dlvsym;
static void       (*actual_glXSwapBuffers)(Display *, GLXDrawable)     = initial_glXSwapBuffers;
static EGLBoolean (*actual_eglSwapBuffers)(EGLDisplay, EGLSurface)     = initial_eglSwapBuffers;

static void initial_glXSwapBuffers(Display *display UNUSED, GLXDrawable drawable UNUSED)
{
    return;
}

static EGLBoolean initial_eglSwapBuffers(EGLDisplay display UNUSED, EGLSurface surface UNUSED)
{
    return 0;
}

static void *initial_dlsym(void *handle, const char *const symbol)
{
    void *(*call_dlsym)(void *, const char *);

    if (symbol) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; interposed[i].symbol; i++)
            if (!strcmp(symbol, interposed[i].symbol))
                return interposed[i].function;
    }

    *(void **)(&call_dlsym) = __atomic_load_n((void **)(&actual_dlsym), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    if (!call_dlsym || call_dlsym == initial_dlsym) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        void     *handle;

        handle = dlopen(LIBDL_PATH, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND | RTLD_NODELETE);
        call_dlsym = _dl_vsym(handle, "dlsym", LIBDL_VERSION, dlsym);
        dlclose(handle);

        if (!call_dlsym || call_dlsym == initial_dlsym || call_dlsym == dlsym) {
            errno = saved_errno;
            return (void *)0;
        }

        __atomic_store_n((void **)(&actual_dlsym), call_dlsym, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        errno = saved_errno;
    }

    return call_dlsym(handle, symbol);
}

static void *initial_dlvsym(void *handle, const char *const symbol, const char *const version)
{
    void *(*call_dlvsym)(void *, const char *, const char *);

    if (symbol) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; interposed[i].symbol; i++)
            if (!strcmp(symbol, interposed[i].symbol))
                if (!interposed[i].version || !version || !strcmp(version, interposed[i].version))
                    return interposed[i].function;
    }

    *(void **)(&call_dlvsym) = __atomic_load_n((void **)(&actual_dlvsym), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    if (!call_dlvsym || call_dlvsym == initial_dlvsym) {
        const int saved_errno = errno;
        void     *handle;

        handle = dlopen(LIBDL_PATH, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND | RTLD_NODELETE);
        call_dlvsym = _dl_vsym(handle, "dlvsym", LIBDL_VERSION, dlvsym);
        dlclose(handle);

        if (!call_dlvsym || call_dlvsym == initial_dlvsym || call_dlvsym == dlvsym) {
            errno = saved_errno;
            return (void *)0;
        }

        __atomic_store_n((void **)(&actual_dlvsym), call_dlvsym, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
        errno = saved_errno;
    }

    return call_dlvsym(handle, symbol, version);
}

void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *const symbol)
{
    if (symbol) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; interposed[i].symbol; i++)
            if (!strcmp(symbol, interposed[i].symbol))
                return interposed[i].function;
    }
    return actual_dlsym(handle, symbol);
}

void *dlvsym(void *handle, const char *const symbol, const char *version)
{
    if (symbol) {
        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; interposed[i].symbol; i++)
            if (!strcmp(symbol, interposed[i].symbol))
                if (!interposed[i].version || !version || !strcmp(version, interposed[i].version))
                    return interposed[i].function;
    }
    return actual_dlvsym(handle, symbol, version);
}

static void init(void) __attribute__((constructor (101)));
static void init(void)
{
    int    saved_errno;
    void  *handle;

    saved_errno = errno;

    handle = dlopen(LIBDL_PATH, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_DEEPBIND | RTLD_NODELETE);
    __atomic_store_n((void **)(&actual_dlsym),  _dl_vsym(handle, "dlsym",  LIBDL_VERSION, dlsym),  __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    __atomic_store_n((void **)(&actual_dlvsym), _dl_vsym(handle, "dlvsym", LIBDL_VERSION, dlvsym), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    dlclose(handle);

    __atomic_store_n((void **)(&actual_glXSwapBuffers), actual_dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "glXSwapBuffers"), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
    __atomic_store_n((void **)(&actual_eglSwapBuffers), actual_dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "eglSwapBuffers"), __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);

    errno = saved_errno;
}

void glXSwapBuffers(Display *dpy, GLXDrawable drawable)
{
    /* TODO: Custom stuff before glXSwapBuffers() */
    actual_glXSwapBuffers(dpy, drawable);
    /* TODO: Custom stuff after glXSwapBuffers() */
}

EGLBoolean eglSwapBuffers(EGLDisplay dpy, EGLSurface surface)
{
    EGLBoolean result;
    /* TODO: Custom stuff before eglSwapBuffers() */
    result = actual_eglSwapBuffers(dpy, surface);
    /* TODO: Custom stuff after eglSwapBuffers() */
    return result;
}
```

If you save the above as `example.c`, you can compile it into `libexample.so` using

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -shared `pkg-config --cflags gl egl` example.c -ldl -Wl,-soname,libexample.so `pkg-config --libs gl egl` -o libexample.so
```

In some cases, you need to modify the `LIBDL_VERSION`. Use

```
find /lib* /usr/ -name 'libdl.*' | while read FILE ; do echo "$FILE:" ; readelf -s "$FILE" | sed -ne '/ dlsym@/ s|^.*@@*|\t|p' ; done
```

to check which API version your libdl uses. (I've seen `GLIBC_2.0` and `GLIBC_2.2.5`; it does not reflect the actual version of the library, but the API version of the `dlsym()` and `dlvsym()` calls.)

The `interposed[]` array contains the modified results for the interposed functions.

I have verified that the above example does not crash with any applications I tried -- including a simple `dlsym()` and `dlvsym()` stress test I wrote --, and that it also interposes the `glXSwapBuffers()` correctly (in `glxgears` and `mpv`).

Questions? Comments?