# What are _nocancel() system calls in linux, and is there a way to use LD_PRELOAD to intercept them

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Please let me know what are the _nocancel() system calls (e.g. __pwrite_nocancel(), and whether there is a way to create an LD_PRELOAD library to intercept those calls.  Here's a bit of the background:

I'm investigating functionality of an Oracle database, and would like to add a small shim layer using LD_PRELOAD to capture information about the call in user space.  I'm aware of other ways of capturing this information using system tap, but using LD_PRELOAD is a hard requirement from the customer. 
 strace shows that this particular process is calling pwrite() repeatedly; similarly, the pstack stack trace shows that __pwrite_nocancel() is being called as the last entry on the stack.  I tried reproducing my own __libc_pwrite() function, and declaring 
`extern ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t numBytes, off_t offset)__attribute__((weak, alias ( "__libc_pwrite")));`

but when I link the library and run nm -a |grep pwrite, I get this:

```
000000000006c190 T __libc_pwrite
000000000006c190 W pwrite
```

in contrast, nm -a /lib64/libpthread.so.0 |grep pwrite gives the following:

```
000000000000eaf0 t __libc_pwrite
000000000000eaf0 t __libc_pwrite64
000000000000eaf0 W pwrite
000000000000eaf0 t __pwrite
000000000000eaf0 W pwrite64
000000000000eaf0 W __pwrite64
0000000000000000 a pwrite64.c
000000000000eaf9 t __pwrite_nocancel
```

I've noticed that the _nocancel version is only 9 bytes ahead of the __pwrite, but looking at the source code, I'm unsure as to where it's being created:

```
/* Copyright (C) 1997, 1998, 2000, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2006
   Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.
   Contributed by Ulrich Drepper <drepper@cygnus.com>, 1997.
   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.
   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, see
   <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.  */

#include <assert.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <endian.h>

#include <sysdep-cancel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <bp-checks.h>

#include <kernel-features.h>

#ifdef __NR_pwrite64            /* Newer kernels renamed but it's the same.  */
# ifdef __NR_pwrite
#  error "__NR_pwrite and __NR_pwrite64 both defined???"
# endif
# define __NR_pwrite __NR_pwrite64
#endif

#if defined __NR_pwrite || __ASSUME_PWRITE_SYSCALL > 0

# if __ASSUME_PWRITE_SYSCALL == 0
static ssize_t __emulate_pwrite (int fd, const void *buf, size_t count,
                 off_t offset) internal_function;
# endif

ssize_t
__libc_pwrite (fd, buf, count, offset)
     int fd;
     const void *buf;
     size_t count;
     off_t offset;
{
  ssize_t result;

  if (SINGLE_THREAD_P)
    {
      /* First try the syscall.  */
      result = INLINE_SYSCALL (pwrite, 6, fd, CHECK_N (buf, count), count, 0,
                   __LONG_LONG_PAIR (offset >> 31, offset));
# if __ASSUME_PWRITE_SYSCALL == 0
      if (result == -1 && errno == ENOSYS)
        /* No system call available.  Use the emulation.  */
        result = __emulate_pwrite (fd, buf, count, offset);
# endif
      return result;
    }

  int oldtype = LIBC_CANCEL_ASYNC ();

  /* First try the syscall.  */
  result = INLINE_SYSCALL (pwrite, 6, fd, CHECK_N (buf, count), count, 0,
               __LONG_LONG_PAIR (offset >> 31, offset));
# if __ASSUME_PWRITE_SYSCALL == 0
  if (result == -1 && errno == ENOSYS)
    /* No system call available.  Use the emulation.  */
    result = __emulate_pwrite (fd, buf, count, offset);
# endif

  LIBC_CANCEL_RESET (oldtype);

  return result;
}

strong_alias (__libc_pwrite, __pwrite)
weak_alias (__libc_pwrite, pwrite)

# define __libc_pwrite(fd, buf, count, offset) \
     static internal_function __emulate_pwrite (fd, buf, count, offset)
#endif

#if __ASSUME_PWRITE_SYSCALL == 0
# include <sysdeps/posix/pwrite.c>
#endif
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The `pwrite_nocancel()` et cetera are not syscalls in Linux. They are functions internal to the C library, and tightly coupled with pthreads and thread cancellation.

The `_nocancel()` versions behave exactly the same as the original functions, except that these versions are not thread cancellation points.

Most I/O functions are cancellation points. That is, if the thread cancellation type is *deferred* and cancellation state is *enabled*, and another thread in the process has requested the thread to be cancelled, the thread will cancel (exit) when entering a cancellation point. See [`man 3 pthread_cancel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html), [`man 3 pthread_setcancelstate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcancelstate.3.html), and [`man 3 pthread_setcanceltype`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setcanceltype.3.html) for further details.

Unfortunately, the `pwrite_nocancel()` and other `_nocancel()` functions are internal (local) to the pthreads library, and as such, are quite difficult to interpose; they're not dynamic symbols, so the dynamic linker cannot override them. At this point, I suspect, but am not sure, that the way to interpose them would involve rewriting the beginning of the library code with a direct jump to your own code.

If they were exported (global) functions, they could be interposed just like any other library function (these are provided by the pthread library, `libpthread`), using the normal approach. (Of my own answers here, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26953010/1475978), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28030139/1475978), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24356162/1475978) informative. Otherwise, just search for *LD_PRELOAD* *example*.)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, and especially for the informative links.  Fortunately, good o' LD_PRELOAD still worked in the end.  After resorting to gdb, and attaching to oracle, and using the 'layout asm' mode, I found that even though it did not appear in the stack, the __pwrite_nocancel was actually a label that was jne'd from the pwrite64 symbol.  After adding the line extern ssize_t pwrite64(int fd, const void *buf, size_t numBytes, off_t offset)__attribute__((weak, alias ( "__libc_pwrite"))); to my code, everything started working.

Comment: @Leo, so the `_nocancel()` variants are only called from the library functions themselves, and thus don't need to be interposed separately; interposing the standard library functions will take care of them, too. Makes sense, really. I was too lazy to go look-see through the pthreads sources to find out if the _nocancel() variants were called from anywhere else. They being local to the library means that you should not be able to call them directly anyway -- unless you obtain a function pointer to them, somehow. The dynamic linker definitely won't.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to interpose via `LD_PRELOAD`, you need to look at the same symbols rtld is using. Therefore, instead of `nm -a`, use `objdump -T`. If the symbol you want is not listed there, you cannot interpose it. All exported glibc symbols have a "version" string that is compared by rtld and allows having multiple versions of the same symbol (this is why even `nm -D` is not useful -- it doesn't show the versions). To interpose something, you should have the same version string. This can be done using a version script (see `info ld`), the `.symver` asm directive or a macro that invokes that directive. Note that symbols with a "private" version may change at any new revision of the libc, and that other symbols may be superseded by new ones at any new version (the symbols still work, but applications compiled against the new version don't use them anymore).

Comment: Thanks for the info; fortunately, though LD_PRELOAD seems to override the function regardless of the version symbol (perhaps because there was only one version defined), so I didn't have to go through the hassle of cherry-picking the symbol.  When I do objdump -T, the libpthread symbols indeed appear as GLIBC-2.2.5, and mine as Base.  After a bit of digging around, the __pwrite_nocancel() was actually jne'd from the pwrite64 symbol, which I had not exported.  After adding another weak alias to that, it's all fine.  Thanks again for replying.