# Firefox shows only blank pages - even about:config is just white

Tags: firefox, citrix

From one day to another Firefox shows only blank white pages:
[image]

I'v tried

- starting Firefox in `--safe-mode`
- starting Firefox with `--ProfileManager` and creating a new profile
- opening Developer Tools - but they did not show up
- removing `~/.mozilla`
- reinstalled Firefox with `sudo apt purge firefox && sudo apt install firefox`

Nothing was working. Firefox even shows no error messages. Chromium still worked as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When starting Firefox with `strace` I noticed by accident a library called `libAppProtection.so`. It is located at `/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/ -lah
total 188K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Feb 23 17:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Jan  1 08:24 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   56 Feb 23 17:35 libAppProtection.so -> /usr/local/lib/AppProtection   /libAppProtection.so.1.6.7.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 175K Jan  1 08:24 libAppProtection.so.1.6.7.3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   44 Jan  1 08:24 .XInputEventIDs
$
```

After renaming the folder I got a lot of error messages - on every command I execute, even in the shell - but Firefox worked again as expected.

It turned out that `libAppProtection.so` was part of the [Citrix Workspace App SDK](https://www.citrix.com/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html) 2101 which I installed some days ago. It needs a restart of Firefox to make problems. So I removed the current installation with

```
$ sudo apt purge icaclient
[...]
$
```

and downloaded the workspace app and installed it without the app protection:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the issue I've been having as well.