# dlsym() + RTLD_NEXT doesn't work as expected on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, c, posix, citrix, dlsym

I'm faced a strange runtime behavior on Ubuntu 20.04 (gcc v 9.3.0) when using `dlsym()` call.

Please, see below a simple example:

- **file test.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C"
{
    void __cxa_throw(void *ex, void *info, void (*dest)(void *))
    {
        std::cout << "__cxa_throw() invoked \n";

        static void (*const rethrow)(void *, void *, void (*)(void *)) __attribute__((noreturn))
            = (void (*)(void *, void *, void (*)(void *)))dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__cxa_throw");

        std::cout << "addr in lib=" << &rethrow << "\n";

        rethrow(ex, info, dest);

        std::terminate();
    }
}
```

- **file main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
  throw std::runtime_error("error");
}

int main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Build these 2 files as following:

```
g++ -fPIC -std=c++17 test.cpp -g -c -o test.o
g++ -shared ./test.o -o libtest.so
g++ main.cpp -std=c++17 -g -pedantic -L./ -ltest -ldl
```

Feeding ldd to ***./a.out*** gives :

```
ldd a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe01186000)
    /usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so (0x00007f1dbd738000)
    libtest.so (0x00007f1dbd733000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1dbd708000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd526000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1dbd50b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd319000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1dbd2f4000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd1b7000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f1dbd18d000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd17b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1dbd964000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd02c000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd024000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd01c000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f1dbd007000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f1dbcfed000)
```

We can see that `libtest.so` is resolved before `libstdc++.so`.
My expectation how this code should work :

- `__cxa_throw()` is defined in 2 shared libraries : `libtest.so` and `libstdc++.so`
- when exception is being thrown in `foo()` call, the `__cxa_throw` is resolved from `libtest.so` and invoked.
- invoking `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__cxa_throw");` makes lookup for `__cxa_throw` further in the list of shared libraries, found in libstdc++.so and invoked.

This works as expected on all platforms except Ubuntu 20.04 where `rethrow` is referencing the `__cxa_throw` from `libtest.so` (but not `libstc++.so`) and thus causing endless recursion.

Please assist as I'm puzzled with runtime behavior.

Comment: have you tried calling `dlsym( RTLD_DEFAULT, "__cxa_throw" );` before `dlsym( RTLD_NEXT, ... );` ?

Comment: What is `/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so`?  Does that exist on systems that **don't** have problems with `dlsym()`?  You might want to see which `dlsym()` you're calling...

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Does `sudo apt-get purge icaclient` followed by rebooting make it work? Does it work if you try it on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Uninstalling `icaclient` helped. This is very unexpected hook made by citrix client. Thank for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "app protection" component of the Citrix ICA client installs the library `/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so` and adds an entry for it to `/etc/ld.so.preload`, causing it to be loaded into every dynamically-linked process. Among other things, this library replaces the `dlsym` function with its own. (If you're curious how this doesn't just always break everything by going into an infinite loop, see [How can I intercept dlsym calls using LD_PRELOAD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15599026/7509065). It actually seems like Citrix's code may have been copied and pasted straight from that answer.) The problem is that since `RTLD_NEXT` depends on being able to inspect the return address, special care is required to avoid breaking that when hooking `dlsym`, and they didn't take that special care. As a result, `RTLD_NEXT` will look for the symbol in the next library after `libAppProtection.so`, instead of in the next library after your code, which causes exactly the problem you ran into.

Here's some choices for what to do about it:

- Complain to Citrix support until they fix their buggy library
- `sudo apt-get purge icaclient` (and optionally reinstall it afterwards, but [choosing no when asked about the app protection component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66337541/7509065))
- Modify your program to load the real `dlsym` from `libdl.so` and then use it for any calls that use `RTLD_NEXT`

Comment: THB, I was very surprised to see that citrix client hooks `dlsym` and the hook itself does wrong job. Thanks a lot for answering!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, the issue was caused by hook done by Citrix ICA client that hooks `dlsym()` and thus causes wrong `dlsym()` to be invoked.